# Firebase current user login issue

Tags: firebase-authentication, webhooks, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I built a dialogflow bot which is integrated to my fb page. I have used firebase authentication for the login flow.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Scenario: First user A logs in and then user B logs in from their respective fb messenger chat windows. Now, when the user A tries to get the current user details from the above code, he is being returned with user info of user B. Why is this happening?

I am trying to check if user is already logged in to the firebase in my webhook node js. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I assume you mean "they are being returned with user info of user B"? Can you also clarify where this code is running - is it in a Dialogflow webhook or on the client? Can you show the includes you're using to load the firebase library?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I meant user B. Sorry for the late reply.  The code is on the webhook.  Includes---->> var firebase = require("firebase");
const firestore = require('firebase-admin');